# Are there any traps that reset in Majin and the Forsaken Kingdom?

Tags: majin-and-the-forsaken-kingdom

Are there any traps that can be reset in *Majin and the Forsaken Kingdom*? Once a trap is triggered, it does not seem to be reset. Are there any I can reset? I am just a few trap kills short of the **Trap Master** achievement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explosive barrels and mines count as traps, and those appear to be the only ones that can be reset consistently. Some of the others are story related and you have to reload to the point before them.

The reset for explosive items can be triggered by having a zone reload. You can accomplish this by going to a save point, changing and outfit, and exiting out. With the explosive things, you sometimes have to have the enemy hurt prior to killing them with the item.

I actually went the route of reloading the area with the boulder and found that to be quicker and more reliable way to get the achievement.

Comment: Yeah, I've gone way past the point where I can do a rollback to having a boulder.

Comment: I actually ran through the beginning of the game again after defeating it to get to that point. There are a few other traps along the way to the boulder. The explosives will work, but it just seemed to take too long to get them hurt enough, but not dead to then get them with an explosion.